# Can't resolve 'fs' in nextjs with custom express server

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js, fs, dotenv

I add fs to my nextjs project and received the following error:

*Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/neven/Development/next-js/node_modules/dotenv/lib'*

I found that to resolve this issue, I should add **config.node = { fs: 'empty' }** to my next.config.js file.
The problem is that when I add that config param, dotenv plugin stops working, that is env variables are not loaded on client side.

This is my next.config.js file, which works without any issues.

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const path = require('path')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

dotenv.config()

module.exports = withCSS({
  webpack: config => {
    config.plugins = config.plugins || []

    config.plugins = [
      ...config.plugins,

      // Read the .env file
      new Dotenv({
        path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
        systemvars: true,
      }),
    ]

    return config
  },
})
```

And then when I add *fs: 'empty'*, it looks like this:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const path = require('path')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

dotenv.config()

module.exports = withCSS({
  webpack: config => {
    config.plugins = config.plugins || []

    config.node = {
      fs: 'empty'
    }

    config.plugins = [
      ...config.plugins,

      // Read the .env file
      new Dotenv({
        path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
        systemvars: true,
      }),
    ]

    return config
  },
})
```

Do you have any suggestions on how I could work this thing out?

Let me know in case additional details are needed.

Answer (score 2):

I found out what the issue was; dotenv plugin is working correctly, but I was trying to get the variables on client side, and that is not possible in this way.

The solution to use env variables on client side is to add ***env: { EXAMPLE: 'helloWorld' }*** to next.config.js file.

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const path = require('path')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

dotenv.config()

module.exports = withCSS({
  env: { EXAMPLE: 'helloWorld' },
  webpack: config => {
    config.plugins = config.plugins || []

    config.node = {
      fs: 'empty'
    }

    config.plugins = [
      ...config.plugins,

      // Read the .env file
      new Dotenv({
        path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
        systemvars: true,
      }),
    ]

    return config
  },
})
```

Comment: I had the problem with 

import '@ testing-library / jest-dom / extend-expect'; 

which led to a missing node module fs during production build. 

./node_modules/css/lib/stringify/source-map-support.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

After I had integrated the Webpack configuration 1 to 1 into my next.config.js everything now works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that your client-side can't access the environment variables.

[Started NextJS 9.4](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables), you can use `.env*` files to add your environment variables.

For your client-side to get access access to the environment variables, you just need to prefix them with **NEXT_PUBLIC_**

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_YOUR_KEY="keykeykey"
```

These can be accessible with:

```
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_YOUR_KEY
```

Comment: I initially got confused that we only need to access the variables with the prefix but YOUR_KEY also needs the prefix NEXT_PUBLIC_ Thanks man!